# Attach Timestamp and SI_ID to a schedule report using SDK

Tags: business-objects

I am scheduling a report using Java to a file location, I need to append `%SI_ID%` and `Timestamp(%SI_STARTTIME%)` to the name of Schedule report.
I am able to generate reports to the file location but I don't know how to apply placeholders on the schedule report name using Java SDK.

If someone has some working code or know how to do this please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution... just attach %SI_ID% or %SI_STARTTIME% with the instance name and BO scheduler will replace with the correct values.